# Nodejs multiple thread or process crawler

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, web-crawler

First I not know much about nodejs multi thread and multi process. But i have a idea and i'm not sure the multi-thread does achieve it.

There is a api, when call it, i will generate a list, the store all web links, the list has a big length, so i split the list like this:

```
const list = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, ..., 1000]
const splitList= [[1, 2, 3], [...], ,[...], [998, 99, 1000]]
```

Then begin crawl the links:

```js
let i = 0
while (i < splitList.length) {
  await Promise.all(splitList[i].map(async link => {
    crawl(link)
  }))
  i++
}
```

The idea is:

[image]

Maybe This way sounds crazy, but if it works, Will save much time.

Comment: What is *mutil*?

Comment: I'm so sorry , I mean multiple

Comment: It's not unheard of, queues/workers exist for a reason when the task is huge. So continue, if you want to avoid workers, just process manager it and run fork it twice. :)

Comment: What does `crawl` do? You don't need multiple processes or even multithreading in nodejs to make parallel requests. Assuming `crawl` is an asynchronous, promise-returning function your approach works just fine and will batch every chunk of the `splitList` concurrently.

Comment: You need to write `.map(async link => { await crawl(link); })`, `.map(link => { return crawl(link); })`, `.map(link => crawl(link))`, or just `.map(crawl)` to create the right array of promises.